# Why do my bosses all have minimal defense?

Tags: warning-forever

[image: Warning Forever's Catastrophe With Penta-Forces Custom.]

I tried to make  a slow motion [Warning Forever](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warning_Forever) run today (Fraps slows the game by approximately half), with kind of disappointing results (my 999 seconds countdown only run fell short of Grace's <s>180 seconds</s> three ships regular run played in real time by some 10 million points — pictured is the last boss I fought).

Something I noticed, however, is that the game never thought it would be a good idea to have the bosses improve their defense.

What does the Defense score mean and what makes it increase? Am I missing something here, or do I just die too easily?

Comment: My game strategy for this one run was to dig my way to the core as fast as possible, then shooting at it until it went down. A lot of bosses took more than a minute to go down this way. When I switched to chopping bosses off in smaller pieces, bosses started going down in 20-30 seconds each (I also stopped using the directional weapons). This still didn't prompt them to upgrade their Defense, though...

Comment: I was doing a 3-lives run, not a 3 minute run. I don't think I could've possibly gotten through **48** stages in only 3 minutes. So, be proud of your 48 million; your actual score rate was far higher than mine. ♪

Comment: @Grace Well, I _was_ cheating by playing at half speed ;)

Comment: I know what defense *does* (outer parts tend to be a lot more beefy and the Shielding effect happens more often and lasts much longer), but I don't know why your bosses have such low defense.

Comment: My guess is, because your playing with lives instead of time, the bosses figure they only need to kill you and don't need to worry about their own preservation. They level up with only a certain amount of stat points to allocate (as well as weapons based on how well they've killed you with said weapons) so if they need to only kill you three times to "win", they probably would allocate everything to offense. See if it makes a difference with time-based play instead of lives-based play. Just a complete guess though.

Comment: @Resorath Play mode doesn't affect boss evolution (otherwise, the custom game modes would be pretty wonky); as well, badp was doing a countdown from 999, not lives-based play.

Comment: Oh well never mind then. I never did understand "boss evolution" aside from their weapon choice.

Comment: @Resorath I can actually explain a fair amount of it (not actual algorithms, but more how it determines most of its growth patterns), but that'd be content for a question of its own. ♪

Comment: Yeah, I built the boss from the sides so that it would be very fast to attack him from below. :) Now that I read the article about it on Wikipedia, I feel smarter than I am for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a description of how to evolve bosses from a [Jay is Games commenter](http://jayisgames.com/archives/2006/04/warning_forever.php):

> First, you need to understand how to grow parts.
>   To get Wide, you need to get horizontal extensions.
>   To get Attack, you need vertical extensions.
>   To get Armor, you need to attack the guns in close combat.
>
> Now the parts that will be created:
>   Wide top = Wings
>   Wide bottom = Arms
>   Attack top = Buster
>   Attack bottom = Striker
>   Armor top = Tornado
>   Armor bottom = Defender
>
> Now the evolution flow.
>   Pure Heart = The first ship, and the base and foundation of the rest of the ships.
>   Intial forms:
>   W=Wide, A=Attack, M=Armor
>   Pure Heart + Top part + Bottom part
>   PH+W+W=Double Wider
>   PH+W+A=Wide Attacker
>   PH+W+M=Wide Armor
>   PH+A+W=Attack Wider
>   PH+A+A=Double Armor
>   PH+A+M=Attack Armor
>   PH+M+W=Armored Wider
>   PH+M+A=Armored Attacker
>   PH+M+M=Double Armor
>
> **Evolution 1 forms**
>   Double Wider > Wing Arms
>   Wide Attacker > Wing Striker
>   Wide Armor > Wing Defender
>   Attack Wider > Buster Arms
>   Double Attacker > Buster Striker
>   Attack Armor > Buster Defender
>   Armored Wider > Tornado Arms
>   Armored Attacker > Tornado Striker
>   Double Armor > Tornado Defender
>
> **Evolution 2 forms**
>   Wing Arms > Asura
>   Wing Striker > Pheonix
>   Wing Defender > Hammerhead
>   Buster Arms > Scorpion
>   Buster Striker > Muramasa
>   Buster Defender > Big Magnum
>   Tornado Arms > Hekatoncheir
>   Tornado Striker > Berserker
>   Tornado Defender > ISE-ONE*
>
> **Evolution 3 forms**
>   Asura, Pheonix, Scorpion, Muramasa > Infinity
>   Hammerhead, Big Magnum > Catastrophe
>   Hekatoncheir, Berserker > Armageddon
>
> *ISE-ONE no longer evolves into a third form.

That's a bit hard to visualize, so here's a nifty chart showing evolution through tiers 2 and 3:

[image: Boss flowchart]